# Code Comparison and Performance

Tags: java, performance

In a high-performance library implementation, I saw this code

```
double meanQ=0; 
int counter=0;
for(...){
    //some cycle with many iterations where meanQ and counter are incremented
}
meanQ /= (double)counter + 0.001D;
```

The last line looks confusing to me. I would just do

```
if(counter>0)
    meanQ /= counter;
```

When `counter` is `0`, then `meanQ` is also `0`, otherwise it is divided by `counter`. It is also (slightly) more accurate as a mean, there are no casts, it is simpler to understand. Afaik, the `if` and the sum should have a similar performance, but I cannot test that on my machine right now.

Is there any difference between both approaches? Is the current library version better performing or are there any other motives to choose it over my suggestion?

Comment: Well, the cast is definitely unnecessary there. int + double always gives a double. The D suffix is also superfluous. This does not encourage trust in library quality at all :-)

Comment: Try the correct solution (`if ...`) and benchmark both versions. Does it even make a difference?

Comment: Here it does not, since in comparison with the loop, the performance is negligible. I wanted the answer for future reference mostly. However, I don't have a machine to test it on atm, so I can't benchmark them

Answer (score 0):

If `meanQ /= (double)counter + 0.001D;` is within a loop, then this code is faster than having the latter code:

```
 if(counter>0)
    meanQ /= counter;
```

in the loop.

This is because, for every iteration, it needs to check the counter for 0, and having the if() will make quite a difference.

The sum and if() will not have the same complexity .

Comment: floating point operations (especially with double precision) are relatively slow, therefore I assume that you are wrong.

Comment: I believe that on modern day processors, floating point operations aren't slower, there being vector registers which carry out 4 or 8 floating point operations per cycle. Unless the device has really limited resources, like an embedded system, the if() will be more significant in declining performance in comparison, imho.

Comment: It is outside the `if`, though. I've edited the question for clarity.

Comment: Also, even assuming that floating point operations are just as fast as regular operations, I'm assuming the `if` would have a similar performance due to *branch prediction*. Although the point is just hypothetical :P

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot agree with your statement that "this code is better". It might be faster, but the result is wrong.

Comment: Edited . Depending on  where the code is applied, I assumed a negligible difference wouldn't matter. Though it may matter on a larger scale. You're right.